# How to get a user to register only after admin accepts it in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to make a user, when registering in my application, have to **choose a group** (if it does not already exist, that he can create one and become admin automatically) and, when choosing a particular group, **wait for admin accept it**. How can I do this using django? Thanks in advance!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show your code, what you've tried. If you hit a specific issue with your code where something doesn't work as expected and you can't figure it out, then is a good moment to look for answers on SO.

Comment: Sorry, but if it was required to show some kind of code, my question would not have passed. I asked the question that way because I would like an anitial start. So, I appreciate if you can help, otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_active`. When the user registers, just set 'is_active' to false. The process of acceptance can set `is_active` to true. This will ensure that a user does not become an active user until they are approved.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active

EDIT in reply to question:

Have something like this in your signup function/class?

```
if group.exists(): 
    user.is_active = False
```

Comment: It's a great idea! Thank you! It can be a good start! However, do you have any idea how to make the first user, when creating a group, become the superuser of that group automatically?

Comment: In your signup class/function, why wouldn't you just have a conditional? See my edit.